# Symfony 2 translations in external js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, external, twig

I want to put some translations to functions in external Java Script file. It is possible to parse js file e.g. like Twig template?

Answer (score 5):

I can recommend the [BazingaJsTranslationBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaJsTranslationBundle) (the same Bundle that @smoreno suggested, but the name changed in the meantime).

If you don't want to use a Bundle, there is a nice and easy to use workaround: You can define the translated string in a HTML twig file and call it in your external JavaScript file. For example like this

## HTML file

```
{# index.html.twig #}
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        {# Your stuff #}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myTranslatedString = '{{ 'my_string'|trans }}';
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Translation file

```
# messages.en.yml
my_string: 'My Content'
```

## JavaScript file

```
// script.js
alert(myTranslatedString); // Will output 'My Content'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just make yourself a `whatever.js.twig` file and have at it. You will need to make sure the headers and such get properly set.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, could you provide an example?

Comment: this solution doesn't work at all and who wrote it didn't explain how to approach it correctly